# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'bool *'

Tags: c++, class, pointers, boolean

I'm getting said error on this line "b = true". Now Why am I getting this error? Aren't I pointing to TurnMeOn and thus saying TurnMeOn = true?

```
class B{
void turnOn(bool *b){b = true}
};

int main(){
B *b = new B();
bool turnMeOn = false;
b->turnOn(&turnMeOn);
cout << "b = " << turnMeOn << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using pointers all over the place? What is `b` dynamically allocated? `turnOn` should take a reference. (What does `turnOn(0)` do?) You don't want the address of a variable, you want an alias to the variable itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
b->turnOn(&turnMeOn);
```

and

```
   *b = true;
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that passing by pointer here makes the calling code more readable than passing by reference as some of the other comments suggest.

Answer (score 5):

`turnOn` requires a pointer to bool as parameter. You're using it as an actual `bool`. I guess you're looking for a reference, i.e. `bool& b` as parameter declaration in your method.

Comment: +1: In this case, the reference is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 4):

No.  As you've written it, it would need to be `*b = true`.

Alternatively, you could write the function to take a *reference* to a bool, so that

```
void turnOn(bool &b) { b = true; }
```

would be correct.